# php round up decimals not working

Tags: php, math, decimal

I have a bit of code but it is not echoing the correct answer, or in the correct format. I tried the round function but that didnt show anything

```
here is my code

$total_per_year = 308790;

$fat = $total_per_year / 3500;

echo $fat;
```

it is currently showing it as 0.088, but the correct answer is 88.2257142857

how can i do this so it round up to 88.2

Comment: This code does *not* output "0.088"! http://3v4l.org/3vjuJ

Comment: How are you getting 0.088?

Comment: yeah, there must be something wrong with the rest of my other code. Nothing seems to be adding up

Answer (score 5):

The `round` function requires two parameters like so:

```
echo round($fat,1);
```

The second parameter being the amount of decimal places you require.

I have had issues previously with round not working as expected and I had to use `number_format`:

```
echo number_format((float)$fat,1,'.','');
```

With 1 being the decimal places required, the full stop being the decimal separator and '', being the thousand separator.

Comment: Well, this beats my answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `round()`

```
echo round($fat, 1); //second argument is precision eg. decimals
```

See this for documentation: https://www.php.net/round

Comment: The second argument should be 1.

Comment: Whoops. I read the question as two decimals. My fault!

Answer (score 0):

right, i worked this out now. I know i kept getting '0.088'. And this is wrong.

Its because i had it like this

```
$total_per_day = number_format($total_per_cup * $number_of_cups);

$total_per_year = number_format($total_per_day * 365);

$fat = round($total_per_year / 3500, 1);

echo $fat;
echo $total_per_year;
```

this is the correct code.

```
$total_per_cup = $type_calorie + $milk_calorie + $sugar_calorie;

$total_per_day = $total_per_cup * $number_of_cups;

$total_per_year = $total_per_day * 365;

$fat = $total_per_year / 3500;



echo json_encode(array('total'=> number_format($total_per_year) , 'perday' => number_format($total_per_day), 'fat'=> round($fat, 1)));
```